# Convert car stereo setup to run from mains supply

Tags: power-supply

I have a car stereo system that I wish to keep once my car is no longer running. I have thought about if I could convert it so that I can power it by a wall plug. I have three things to be powered; the head unit which has a 10amp fuse, a 4channel amp which has a 60amp fuse, and lastly another 4channel amp with a 50amp fuse. They all run off of one car battery currently and so I was trying to see if I could convert this setup to run off of a wall plug in or a few to be able to power them in a garage setting. And simply have to unplug them from the wall when not in use or plug in when I want to use them. Is this feasible, or would it require multiple car batteries chained together with a converter from the wall plug in and constant measuring of voltage on the battery to do the job.

Comment: Check the manual for actual power ratings. The fuses are just for short circuits.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need a 12V power supply capable of providing enough current.  Search for "12V 100amp supply" or similar.

You are looking for something like [THIS](https://www.jameco.com/z/SE-1000-12-MEAN-WELL-AC-to-DC-Power-Supply-Single-Output-12-Volt-83-3-Amp-999-6-Watt_2101542.html).

Adding all your fuses together is overkill.  If you have a way of measuring the system's actual current draw you can size the supply more accurately.

Comment: One: yes, adding the fuse ratings together is overkill.  Two: if you're doing a one-off design, sometimes overkill is nice, because things Just Work, so you can avoid troubleshooting and just listen to music in your garage.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use this for say 2 hours and the battery copes with that, then use a battery charger during the other 22 hours to recharge it.

That saves trying to find what may be quite a large power supply.

Do keep the fuses for each of the items though - shorts across a battery can easily cause fires. I have welded with a 12 volt battery before now...

Answer (score 0):

Normally the power consumption (W) or voltage (V) and current (A) would be furnished in the manual.

The voltage would normally be furnished as 13.8Vdc or as ranging from 11-14V or 11-16V. In any case 13.8Vdc is to be considered.

Should the current not be specified, it could be calculated from the sum total of the RMS output powers specified channel-wise for all units (W=V*I).

Peak values specified are to be halved to get the RMS values.

The total current + 20% could be taken as the current rating of the power supply.

A linear regulated power supply would be quite bulky when compared to an SMPS.

There are instances when a PC SMPS has been used without any noise issues.

A suitable SMPS could be tried out.